# Whats the equivalent of ST_DWithin (PostGIS - PostgreSQL) for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, postgis

I am trying to find an efficient way to do proximity queries, ie to return POINTs which are within a radius from a central POINT.

I understand that PostGIS's [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/) method is a good way to do this in PostgreSQL and that it [uses the INDEX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79961/what-is-difference-between-st-dwithin-and-st-distance-for-proximity-search-in-po).

I am currently using [ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2 [, radius])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html) which returns the minimum spherical distance between Point on a sphere, in meters.

```
SELECT placeNames FROM myPlaces
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(placeLocation, POINT(28.861105, 77.337)) < 10000
```

I'm using the `WHERE` clause to filter the rows. Is the query using the index? If no, is there a better approach to implement the same.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.26 and 8.0.16, both running the default InnoDB database engine.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to check the way the query is executed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: `# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra`
``
`'1', 'SIMPLE', 'myStoreLocations', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2', '100.00', 'Using where'`

Comment: I don't think the spatial index is used here

Comment: I agree. Provided the execution time is not "obscene" I would not think more about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in MySQL, there seems to be no 'more efficient' alternative to `ST_Distance_Sphere` or any other which uses a spatial index.

Answer (score -2):

Firtly SRID set this query 4326 use it;
sample

SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),4326);