# Get all the users within radius from MySQL with Spatial Point

Tags: php, mysql, angular, geolocation, leaflet

I have a MySQL table on my local server. The table includes latitude, longitude and POINT(latitude, longitude) for each user. I am trying to get all the id user within 10 kilometres from center.

I would like not to use latitude and longitude but only the Point. But I don't know how to do it. I also heard about **SRID** to modify in the POINT but I did not quite understand

Here is my table for the moment

```
#   Name        Type
1   lat         decimal(10,8)   
2   lng         decimal(11,8)       
3   latlng      point
4   id_user     int(10)
```

Indexes

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
latlng  SPATIAL No      No      latlng (32)     A   No
```

How could I do that in PHP?

Just for information, what is the best thing between using a Point and latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 0):

I am a postgres/postgis user, but they have equivalents.  If you have the ability to add columns to your table you should convert the lat/lons to Point() objects maybe using something like ST_PointFromText and then you can compare them to each other using ST_Distance()
Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html

Edit: apparently mySql does not have the more efficient ST_DWithin() (See: [Whats the equivalent of ST_DWithin (PostGIS - PostgreSQL) for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56325886/5971072)) so you probably stuck with ST_Distance().

SRID 4326 is a common one for these types of lat/lon coordinate systems.
Ref: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-an-srid.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I need to add a new column in addition to latlng and put in it ST_PointFromText ('POINT(lat long)', 4326) ?

Comment: That is the approach I would take.  When all rows have these geometry columns it is much easier to do the comparisons and such.  The lat/lon column become redundant... you can keep them but you do want to make sure the point column stays in sync if the lat/lon change (via triggers).  Or simply convert the Point back to lat/lon for display if needed.